# How do I set the names of automatically imported files to be their file names in R?

Tags: r, function, import

I'm importing a folder of files according to the package eemR using the following:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(eemR)

importIlliter <- function(file) {
  fluoroFrame <- fread(file) %>% as.data.frame()
  return(
    list(
      file = file,
      x = fluoroFrame[ -1, -1] %>% t() %>% as.matrix() %>% unname(),
      ex = fluoroFrame[ -1, 1] %>% as.numeric(),
      em = fluoroFrame[ 1, -1] %>% as.numeric()
    )
  )
}



folder <- file.path("C:/Users/ejs7c/OneDrive/Desktop/eemR/")

eems <- eem_read(folder, recursive = TRUE, import_function = importIlliter)
```

However, when I import the files, they are simply just called [[1]], [[2]].. and so on - Is there a way to make it so the files retain their names when I import them? i.e., one is called Raman520, and I would like it to be called that when it's imported as an eem (in the final line of the above code).

My eventual goal is to automate some functions within the eemR package, but I'm assuming I can still do that even if I let the files keep their names.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you already use `tidyverse` a way to assign the `file` to name of list is

```
names(eems) <- map_chr(eems, pluck, "file")
```

A demo

```r
library(purrr)

eems <- list(
  list(file = "file_1"),
  list(file = "file_2"),
  list(file = "file_3"),
  list(file = "file_4")
)

eems
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$file
#> [1] "file_1"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$file
#> [1] "file_2"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]]$file
#> [1] "file_3"
#> 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [[4]]$file
#> [1] "file_4"

names(eems) <- map_chr(eems, pluck, "file")

eems
#> $file_1
#> $file_1$file
#> [1] "file_1"
#> 
#> 
#> $file_2
#> $file_2$file
#> [1] "file_2"
#> 
#> 
#> $file_3
#> $file_3$file
#> [1] "file_3"
#> 
#> 
#> $file_4
#> $file_4$file
#> [1] "file_4"

eems[["file_1"]]
#> $file
#> [1] "file_1"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Sinh, do Iadd that at the very end of my code?

Comment: Yes add it to the very end of your current code.

Comment: Thank you; I did that, but it made the entire path the names of the variables

Comment: I do not understand the eems <- list portion of your example; does this stop it from just naming them the whole path when I eventually do the name function? I have a lot of samples, so I'd like to be able to do this without typing out all of the name values in the list function if possible

Comment: It has to be full path as what would happen if there are file with same name in different sub-directory?

Comment: My example is just a trying to replicate your `eems` list as you didn't share what's in your data by `dput`- for more information reference here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example